# Controlling the direction of JavaScript .show() / .toggle()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, transition

I'm using JavaScript's `.toggle()` to have this  appear/ disappear:

```
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    padding: 15px;
}
```

However, over the duration of the animation it starts from the **top-left** corner and expands out to the **bottom-right** corner of the `div`.

Ideally, I'd like to start it from the both **top corners** and expand downwards to both b**ottom corners** evenly.

I thought the **CSS** `transition-origin` property might have an effect, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about jQuery's `toggle` method, so I [looked in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), and sure enough it gives some helpful info. (This is a gentle hint that before coming to StackOverflow you should try solving the problem on your own, including looking at any relevant documentation online).

> The .toggle() method animates the width, height, and opacity of the
>   matched elements simultaneously.

The documentation doesn't give any info about customizing how `toggle` does its animation, so it looks like you're stuck. If I'm understanding you correctly, it seems like you want the element to animate only the height and *not* the width, so it stays the same width as it toggles and just animates the height. I don't see any way of doing that with jQuery's `toggle`.

BUT WAIT! It looks like jQuery has another method called `slideToggle` which does exactly what you want. It's just like `toggle` except it only animates the height and keeps the width the same. Hooray!

http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Moral of the story: if you're using a third party Javascript library like jQuery, you really need to get comfortable finding the information you need in the online documentation my friend. :)

Comment: Thank you. I did spend some time searching before coming here. I guess I'm not 100% familiar with Stack Overflow etiquette, I thought asking a question along this line was okay. I'll try to brush up on my documentation skimming. This is exactly what I was looking for though, perfect solution for me.

Comment: @Koda no worries! Generally people on SO want to see that you made an attempt, some info about what you tried, and what specific issue you're trying to address. Many problems have been answered already on SO or elsewhere and can be found through a simple Google search. For example to help with this problem I simply Google'd "jquery toggle height only".

Answer (score 1):

I would start a height of 0 and the animate the height property.

```js
function toggle() {
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    if (el.className) {
      el.className = '';
    } else {
      el.className = 'grow';
    }
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  width:200px;
  height: 0;
}

.grow {
  height: 200px;
  transition: height 2s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to run with the slideToggle() method mentioned above because it is the simplest in this case, but this looks like a neat solution too and is probably similar to what I would have cooked up if left to my own devices. I appreciate it!

Comment: I personally would use a pure CSS method like this as the resulting animation will use your devices GPU and give you a smoother result. This makes a big difference on tablets and phones.